# Regular Expression in R with grep

Tags: r, regex

I'm struggling with regular expressions again, so I would be happy if anyone can help.

I need to extract strings from some patterns:

1)
`"b[(Intercept) Subject:352]"`, where `Subject:352` is the random pattern I want to get.

2)
`"b[Days Subject:369]"`, where `Days` and `Subject:369` are random patterns, and I want to get the both matches, `Days` and `Subject:369`.

3)
`"r_Subject.369.Days."`, where `Subject.369` and `.Days.` are random patterns, and I want to get `Subject.369` and `Days` (w/o dots).

what are the related regex-pattern to use with `grep()` or similar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `gsub("b\\[\\(Intercept\\) (.*)\\]", "\\1", "b[(Intercept) Subject:352]")`
2. `gsub("b\\[(.*) (.*)\\]", "\\1", "b[Days Subject:369]")` and `gsub("b\\[(.*) (.*)\\]", "\\2", "b[Days Subject:369]")`
3. `gsub("r_(.*)\\.(.*)\\.", "\\1", "r_Subject.369.Days.")` and `gsub("r_(.*)\\.(.*)\\.", "\\2", "r_Subject.369.Days.")`